# How index results by ID in array output python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the following calculation below, I am trying to get the results , with their cust_id for each customer.

```
matrix_data = np.arange(125).reshape(5,5,5)

customer_data = pd.DataFrame({"cust_id": ['x111', 'x222', 'x333'],
                              "state": [2, 3, 2],
                              "amount": [1, 2, 5],
                              "year": [2, 3, 4]})

state = customer_data['state'] -1
amount = customer_data['amount'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
year = customer_data['year']
cust_id=customer_data['cust_id']
results = matrix_data[year, state] * amount
```

desired output example:
x111([[ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59],...

Comment: and, what are your trying to do?

Comment: have to agree @mozway, have no idea what's the desired output

Comment: sorry typo, I just want results by cust_id

Comment: The logic is still missing. If I tell you `a = 1 ; b = 1` I want `c = 1`, can you guess if I want `c = a*b`, `c = a**b`, `c = a and b`, `c = a or b`, or probably dozens of other possibilities? You **must** be explicit.

Comment: It might be helpful to point out that this is a follow-up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73303335/14627505) question.

Comment: Please, include the full desired output. Note that since you have removed `- 1` from `state`, then the output won't be `[ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59]`. Instead, it will be `[ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64]`.

Comment: @VladimirFokow mistake, edited to add in the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
Dict_res = dict(zip(cust_id, results))
```

Answer (score 0):

If that’s what you want, you can create a dataframe with columns that are the rows of the `results`, and set the column names as `cust_id`.

```py
pd.DataFrame(results.T, columns=cust_id.tolist())
```

Comment: This answer would benefit with additional explanation to improve its value for future readers.

Comment: @EricJin, added some explanation